# response on job acceptance

Tags: phrases

I want to open my mail with the following sentence:

> It's great to hear that you have chosen me for the position!

But after talking with a friend he suggests that I should change the sentence to the following:

> It's great that you have selected me for the position!

What would you guys suggest? 
If any more context is needed let me know so I can clarify.

Comment: Either is fine. To my ear the combined "It's great to hear that I have been selected for the position!" works, but that's just one opinion.

Comment: It feels to me like Workplace SE would be a better place to ask this. Though '*I'm delighted to receive your offer*' would be my preference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of those convey the same idea, so I don't think one is better than the other.

I wonder if you really want to use the word "selected" or "chosen" though. When I look for a job, I see it as a mutual benefit - in exchange for some salary, they get my talents and work ethic. Of course the company needs to select/choose me from other candidates their applicant pool, but I wouldn't accept the job unless I thought I'd be happy doing it. It's only when our (the company and my) interests coincide that I take the job.

I don't mean to push my philosophies on you, I only mean to ask whether this is the message you want to send. If not, you might consider:

> Great! I'm happy to receive your offer, as I also think this would be a good fit for me.